# Error : The file has been modified by SHAREPOINT/system

Tags: document-library, check-out, file, check-in, spfile

I am creating .docx file using template of SharePoint Library and uploading it to the library. But I am facing an error while `CheckOut()`. Below is my code.

```
public void UpdateAndCreateFile(SPWeb web)
{
    try
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            string TemplateUrl = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                TemplateUrl = "template path";
            }
            catch { }


            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            SPList olist = web.Lists["Document Library"];
            String url = olist.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.ToString();


            string foldername = Convert.ToString("Foldername in document library");
            SPFolder newfolder = web.GetFolder(url + "/" + foldername);

            if (!newfolder.Exists)
            {
                SPFolderCollection folders = web.GetFolder(url).SubFolders;
                //Create new folder
                folders.Add(foldername);
            }

            SPFile file = null;

            file = web.GetFile("Your Document templated full path");

            if (file != null)
            {
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                Stream readStream = file.OpenBinaryStream(); //file is SPFile type
                SPFile uploadedFile = newfolder.Files.Add(newfolder.Url + @"/" + "NewDocName.docx", readStream, true);
                uploadedFile.CheckOut();
                SPListItem listitem = uploadedFile.Item;
                // Details is mapped in document
                listitem["Details"] = "this content will add in document";
                listitem.Update();
                uploadedFile.Update();
                uploadedFile.CheckIn(string.Empty);
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle exception here
    }

}
```

Where I am going wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Remove the first web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;. On topic: you don't need uploadedFile.Update();

Comment: thanks. but i am getting error in checkout() and am directly thrown to catch block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get a new instance of the SPFile object right before you try the `.CheckOut()` instruction. I may be wrong, but I think you are experiencing a pretty common transaction related issue.

```
if (file != null)
        {
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            Stream readStream = file.OpenBinaryStream(); //file is SPFile type
            SPFile uploadedFile = newfolder.Files.Add(newfolder.Url + @"/" + "NewDocName.docx", readStream, true);

            var fileUrl = SPUtility.GetFullUrl(web, uploadedFile.Url);
            uploadedFile = web.GetFile(fileUrl);
            // also check with 'uploadedFile=uploadedFile.Item.File;', 
            // I think it may work even this way.

            uploadedFile.CheckOut();
            SPListItem listitem = uploadedFile.Item;
            // Details is mapped in document
            listitem["Details"] = "this content will add in document";
            listitem.Update();
            uploadedFile.Update();
            uploadedFile.CheckIn(string.Empty);
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
```